# How to define a PHP function with a parameter accepting a fixed set of values?

Tags: php, function, constants

How can I define a PHP function with a parameter accepting a fixed set of values similar to `filter_var` which accepts as argument various values as in caps:

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

I am guessing it will be something like:

```
function f(int $params) { ... }
```

but the question is how to make my own fixed caps typed associations?

Example to clarify:

Currently I have 2 functions:

```
function defineDirConstant($constant, $dirname) {
    if (is_dir($dirname) && is_readable($dirname)) {
        define(__NAMESPACE__ . '\\' . $constant, $dirname . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
    } else {
        // some other logic
    }
}

function defineFileConstant($constant, $filename) {
    if (is_file($filename) && is_readable($filename)) {
        define(__NAMESPACE__ . '\\' . $constant, $filename);
    } else {
        // some other logic
    }
}
```

which I am willing to combine into one:

```
function defineFilesystemConstant($constant, $filename, int $type) {
    // some logic considering the $type
}
```

I know in this particular case I can use a Boolean for type but my question is in general: how to make a humanly readable parameter which is able to be typed as text. E.g. the function call would be

```
f("ONE", "foo.txt", TYPE_FILE);
f("BAR", "bar", TYPE_DIR);
f("JIM", "jimcarrey", TYPE_SOMETHING_ELSE);
```

I hope that clarifies.

Comment: I don't think you actually want this, so many runtime errors would be thrown if things aren't perfect.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly you want to create a function that will accept either one(or possibly more) arguments that have a constant value? Something like `function f(constant_goes_here, ...){}`?

Comment: Do you mean your function should accept certain constants (like MY_FILTER1, MY_FILTER2, etc.) but not others? In that case there's no built-in way to do this. You'll have to check in the body of the function that the input is within the allowed range.

Comment: Please clarify what you want for example by writing mockup code (even if it's not valid PHP).

Comment: I added a clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the [define()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) function - you can use that to create constants like those used by the `filter_var` function.

In your example, you would create these constants:

```
define('TYPE_FILE', 1);
define('TYPE_DIR', 2);
define('TYPE_SOMETHING_ELSE', 3);
```

which you can then use in, for example, `f("BAR", "bar", TYPE_DIR);`.

Or if you want to avoid global constants, you can scope them using a class:

```
class FileSystemType {
    const FILE = 1;
    const DIR = 2;
    const SOMETHING_ELSE = 3;
}
```

Which you can then access using:

```
f("BAR", "bar", FileSytemType::DIR);
```

Comment: That's something I also thought about but it requires to define these constants globally, not inside the function, which is bad programming style, isn't it?

Comment: @george, well kind of, yes, but that's how PHP does it for its own functions. And if you want to create code exactly as you described it's the only way to do it. Otherwise you can create a class and add constants to it. See my second example.

Comment: I am getting

`PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 3 passed to defineFilesystemConstant() must be an instance of FilesystemType, integer given` 

when calling the function as defined 

`function defineFilesystemConstant($constant, $name, FilesystemType $type) {
}` 

Why is that happening?

Comment: The call is `defineFilesystemConstant("FOO", "foo.txt", FilesystemType::FILE);`

Comment: `FilesystemType::FILE` is an `int` so you need to define your function like so: `function defineFilesystemConstant($constant, $name, int $type) {}`. I don't think you'll be able to more strongly type the parameter. One option would be to define the constant as objects created via something like `new FilesystemType(1)`, `new FilesystemType(2)`, etc. but really that's overkill.

Comment: I tried defining with `int $type` but then the error changes to `... must be an instance of MyNamespece\\int, integer given...`. I am wondering: wouldn't it be more appropriate to set a sub-namespace instead of dealing with a class/interface?

Comment: Ok I think it should be `($constant, $name, integer $type)` actually (not `int`). If it also doesn't work, try to add a backslash, since it's a global type, as in `\integer $type`.

Comment: Tried both. The error transforms into `... must be an instance of integer, integer given...` The only thing that works is to remove the strong typing totally. But that would contradict the whole idea of the main question. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: Looks like scalar types like int only work in PHP 7+ - https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php If you really want to check that it's an int, you can simply check at the beginning of the function with `if (!is_int($type)) throw new \Exception('Int required')`. To be honest I think that any other solution is not worth it or would make the solution needlessly complex.

Comment: Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Look here http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php:

```
function f($req, $opt = null, int ...$params) {
     printf('$req: %s; $opt: %s; number of params: %s'."\n",
       $req, $opt, count($params));
}
```

This function take `$reg` and `$opt` as parameters and the array `$params` hold all next parameters and convert it to `int`

So `f(1,2,3,4)` has `$reg=1 $opt=2, $params=[3,4]`.

Or `f(1,2,3,4,'5')` has `$reg=1 $opt=2, $params=[3,4,5]`.

Know you can check `$params` and only use valid parameters [ENUMS].

To define ENUMS you can do:

```
interface MyEnums {
   const VALUE1 = 1;
   const VALUE2 = 2;
}
```

`echo MyEnums::VALUE1;`

So if you combine these 2 technics you have something simlliar to your example.

`f(1,2,MyEnums::VALUE1,MyEnums::VALUE2);`

Keep the comment from @this.lau_ above in mind.

Comment: But that is for a variable number of params. I am looking for a fixed number of params, just one of them accepting a fixed set of values.

Comment: `filter_var ` works like that. And this are only hints/tips to give a direction to implement your needs. No full solution. Dont make thing complicated if you dont know how to do it :-)  `accepting a fixed set of values` is fully explained by the comment from @this.lau_ `You'll have to check in the body of the function that the input is within the allowed range`  Have a nice try

Comment: Thank you. I will mark his answer as the answer but yours has useful info too.